# How do I import a Form key to another file

Tags: flutter, import, textfield

I have a Textformfield in one file and a Button in another file. I need to import the Form key from the Textformfield into the button file so I can use it to alter the text field. However, it won't recognize the Form key even if I import the file it's in. What am I supposed to?

Comment: show some code please

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the same as you described. But couldn't implement it.
Cause, the **Global form** key doesn't hold its state on another file.
The solution you can follow is to build a reusable text field and pass the form validation as an argument. It works fine.
**You will have to validate the form inside one single Scaffold.**

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can validate the form by moving the code into a single file inside a single scaffold.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

->Make sure the file containing the TextFormField and its form key is exported properly.

->Import the file with the TextFormField into the file where the Button is located using the correct import statement.

->Ensure that the form key is defined as a global variable or part of the class so that it is accessible outside the file.

->When using the form key in the file with the Button, reference it using the correct import path and variable name.

If the issue persists, check for any typos or errors in your code and ensure that the file structure and import statements are correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).